# PLC SFC loop: Can there be more than one token in the loop?

Tags: function, sequential, plc

I am working on a PLC program using M3 Soft for the Crozet Millenium 3, but my question is about SFC/Grafcet functions generally. Can an SFC loop run more than one token at once? Another way of asking this question is, can there be more than one step active at a time in a single loop, for example, when the initial step is activated, and then activated again before the loop completes?

Answer (score 0):

SFCs are just [(black token) Petri nets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petri_net).   Any state can be enabled, in parallel with other states, in principle.

The trick is get cause a state to be enabled that way; it isn't always easy to arrange for this to happen.

Imagine we have states SF1, SF2 ... SFn.  One can arrange for SF1 to enable SF2 and SF3 (using the HORIZONTALBAR symbol, generally called FORK in more general literature on parallelism).   This is rather typical.  Now SF2 can enable SF4 which enables SF5 ... finally enabling SFk.  You can have SFk enable SF1, so now there's a cycle in the sequential function net.  But if I can have SF1 enable SF2 enable ... SFk, surely I could build an SFC where SF1 enables SF3 and SF2, which enables SF1.  And if I do that, I can have *SF1 enable SF1 and SF3*.  Now SF1 manufactures state-enables repeatedly, each triggering SF3.

I can do this with Petri nets, anyway.  Maybe the language standard forbids SFCs from doing this if it did so, they would be less powerful than Petri nets and that would be, well, dumb.

There's an analog of arbitrary networks of SFC states to programs with GOTOs.  You can write GOTOful programs that are very hard to understand; that doesn't mean GOTOs are bad, just that you can misuse anything.  (In fact, arbitrary GOTOs allow one to build finite state machines, which are really useful if you don't have SFCs.   What people mostly write is well-structured code, with standard controlled-GOTO elements (e.g., IF-THEN-ELSE-ENDIF, WHILE DO END, ...) nested cleanly within on another.

Similarly, one can build FORKful petri nets/SFCs.  Usually these are hard to understand, so unless it serves some very significant purpose, one tends to build SFCs out of cleanly nested  FORK-... JOIN pairs.  In such a diagram, you don't get "one state activated again before the loop completes."